# Magento 2.3 is not working in Safari. It works in other browsers

Tags: magento2.3, catalog, browser

1)issue catalogue pages pictures do not load or load very slowly in safari sometimes it goes to a page saying
safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding
2) catalogue to go to page 2 or 3 is the same issue it goes very slow or it crash and say
safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Does your cache directory has the right permission ?
you need to provide full permission to var and pub folder and try re generating them

```
chmod -R 777 var 

chmod -R 777 pub

php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is some browser caching issue. please clear the browser cache or incognito mode of the browser.